# Usar variável em atributos de um Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou criando um pequeno sistema em python3 usando a biblioteca tkinter, nesse sistema há muitos botões e eu gostaria de padronizar as cores usando uma variável, para não precisar ficar escrevendo isso em todos, mais ou menos desse jeito:

```py
padrao = (bg="gray18", fg="green2", activebackground="green2", activeforeground="gray1")

criar_arquivo = Button(container_criar, text="Criar arquivo", command=criar_file, padrao)
```

porém da erro e já tentei de várias formas mas nenhuma funcionou, e não encontrei nada na internet que pudesse me ajudar, existe algum jeito de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar estilo, veja este exemplo:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import * 

root = Tk() 
root.geometry('300x180') 

style = Style() 


# Irá adicionar estilo a todos os botões disponíveis
# mesmo que não estejamos passando estilo
# para cada widget de botão. 
style.configure('TButton', font = 
               ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'), 
                foreground = 'red') 
# botão 1 
btn1 = Button(root, text = 'Quit !',  
                  style = 'TButton', 
             command = root.destroy) 

btn1.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 100) 

# botão 2 
btn2 = Button(root, text = 'Click me !', command = None) 
btn2.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 10, padx = 100) 

root.mainloop()
```